# Syntax error in sql query for laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I'm looking for the distance around a particular point.

I have these items in my db with a lat and long.

I want to get all the results around it for a specified radius.

This is how i get it:

```
    $lat = '51,3';
    $long = '4,3';
    $radius = '5';

    $hamsters = Hamster::select(
           DB::raw("*,
                         ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( lat ) )
                           * cos( radians( long ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                         ) AS distance"))
           ->having("distance", "<", "?")
           ->orderBy("distance")
           ->setBindings([$lat, $long, $lat,  $radius])
           ->get();
```

Now it gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long ) -
>   radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * ' at line 4 (SQL: select *, ( 6371
>   * acos( cos( radians(51,3) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians(4,3) ) + sin( radians(51,3) ) * sin( radians( lat ) )
>   ) ) AS distance from `hamsters` having `distance` < 5 order by
>   `distance` asc)

Anybody a way to fix this?

Comment: Why dont you `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and echo it and see the query that is being generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long is a reserved keyword in mysql [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

You'd have to use backticks (`) around any labels that share the same name as a workaround.